# How to sum based on the dates of the scores?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

So I have two tables. One of the table is for the teachers to key in the date of completion for the topics that they have taught and then the row below the dates is for the teacher to key in the student's individual score based on the topics taught.

How to calculate the sum of the score for each student for different terms, when each term corresponds to different dates? So that in the future, the teacher can change the dates of completion and the sheet should still be able to automatically change the scores in different terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following formula for the first term.

```
=SUMIFS($B3:$E3,$B$2:$E$2,">="&$F$11,$B$2:$E$2,"<="&$G$11)
```

[image]

The formula for the second term is the same as the first except the criteria have changed.

```
=SUMIFS($B3:$E3,$B$2:$E$2,">="&$F$12,$B$2:$E$2,"<="&$G$12)
```

[image]

The overall result is a simple sum of the first and second terms' values.